# Access forms in v-tab item using $refs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to validate forms in v-tab-item, those forms are generated with a v-for, they are added by the user. The form can be one or more depending on the user who add them. The validation is working for other component but I am struggling to validate forms in the v-tab-items using $refs because it is an Array.

Here is the template in child component:

```
<template>
<v-tabs-items v-model="index" class="ubo-container">
    <v-tab-item
        v-for="(shareholder, i) in shareholders"
        :key="i"
    >
        <v-form class="mt-4" ref="form">
            <v-row class="mb-4">
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" class="pa-0 pr-sm-2">
                    <label light>title</label>
                    <v-text-field hide-details="auto" :rules="[v => !!v]" type="text" class="form-input" outlined light v-model="shareholder.firstName" />
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-form>
    </v-tab-item>
</v-tabs-items>
</template>
```

Parent component

```
<template>
<span v-if="step.slug == 'shareholders'">
  <Shareholders ref="shareholders" 
  :shareholders="shareholders" :data="step" />
</span>

<v-btn value="next"  color="primary" class="white--text px-4 py-2" @click="saveAndNext()">Next</v-btn>
</template>

<script>
methods: {
triggerValidation() {
    let _this = this
    let slug = this.steps[this.currentStep].slug

    let valid = true

    if(slug === 'shareholders'){
        // I want the validate to go here.
       for(let forms = 0; forms < _this.$refs[slug][0].$refs.length; 
          forms++){
            if(_this.$refs[slug][0].$refs[forms][0].$el.querySelector('form')){
    valid = _this.$refs[slug][0].$refs[forms][0].$el.querySelector('form').validate();
                break;
            }
       }
       return
        console.log('shareholders')
    }

    // the below is working fine for other forms and I want to do the same if slug is shareholders
    if (
            typeof _this.$refs[slug] !== 'undefined'
            && _this.$refs[slug][0].$refs.form
        ) {
            valid = _this.$refs[slug][0].$refs.form.validate()
        }
    return valid
},
async saveAndNext() {
    let step = this.steps.filter(s => s.index == this.currentStep)
    step = step[0] || {}

    if (!this.triggerValidation()) {
        return false
    }

    switch(step.index){
        case 4:
            for (let i in this.shareholders) {
                this.document = {
                    files: this.shareholders[i].uploadedFiles,
                    id: this.legalEntityIndiviuals.data.response[i].id,
                    countryId: this.shareholders[i].countryId
                };

                hasShareholderDocuments = this.shareholders[i].hasDocuments
            }
        break;
    }
}
}
<script>
```

Comment: Could you share more of the code? It's still unclear how the data is being used and how validation is being applied.